# only synchronize the memory pool transaction by bitcoind daemon

Tags: bitcoind

I want to use bitcoind to only synchronize the memory pool transaction, and close the block synchronization; I am going to monitor the dynamics of the memory pool in real time; are there parameters that can help me do it with bitcoind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to only sync things in the mempool because the blockchain is needed in order to verify mempool transactions. Before transactions can be added to a node's mempool, they need to be validated. This requires knowing the UTXO set, and this can only be learned by also syncing the blockchain.